# Broad question has been made specific

Tags: support

https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14464/4k-tvs-with-hdmi-2-1-ports-that-support-at-least-4k120-with-8bit-rgb

I'v made it specific, please reopen it?

Comment: It was deleted, why? I can not see the content, but the title makes more likely that yes, it is on-topic now. Maybe you could issue a flag, asking the mod for an undelete.